# Convert numeric matrix into categorical in R?

Tags: r, matrix, categories

I have a matrix

```
A <- rbind(c(1,1),c(2,2))
```

and some categories

```
cat <- c("Good","Bad", "Ugly")
```

I want to transform A into the corresponding categories "Good" <- 1, "Bad" <- 2, "Ugly" <- 3. But using `cat`, I get

```
> cat[A]
[1] "Good" "Bad"  "Good" "Bad"
```

How can I obtain the correct conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transpose the matrix first using `t()`:

```
> cat[t(A)]
#> [1] "Good" "Good" "Bad"  "Bad"
```

Or, in case you want the result to be a matrix, you can convert it back:

```
> matrix(cat[A], ncol = ncol(A))
#>      [,1]   [,2]  
#> [1,] "Good" "Good"
#> [2,] "Bad"  "Bad"
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is matching with a named `vector` or key/val pairs to replace the values in 'A' and then assign it back to 'A' with `[]` to keep the structure of the initial vector

```
A[] <- names(setNames(c(1:3), cat)[A])
A
#    [,1]   [,2]  
#[1,] "Good" "Good"
#[2,] "Bad"  "Bad"
```

NOTE that

```
A[] <- cat[A]
```

should also work given the index are from ordered from 1 to 3.  The first case mentioned is a general case